# New search tab page on Chromium defaults to "fvdsearch? Why?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

The URL bar still uses Google by default for search, but if I click ona suggested link or anything like that, it opens a new tab with fvdsearch as the search provider? I don't understand why. Is it some kinda malware or something? Oh yeah, I'm using 12.04. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you installed an Extension that changed your default search engine or a Windows system got a malware which changed the engine. You should go to your preferences, remove any suspicious plugin/extension, and change your preferences to the default in `about:settings`.